# byobu no longer launches at SSH login

Tags: ssh, byobu

byobu no longer launches automatically when I SSH into my server.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling automatic launch, to no avail.

When I manually launch byobu, it works. However, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> takes me back to the prompt on my server instead of detaching the SSH session and taking me back to my local client.

This is totally puzzling me as I have used byobu for years now. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some troubleshooting and adding lots of `echo`'s in byobu's script files I can answer the question myself.

I had added a `set LESS=-JFMNQRSi` to my `.bashrc`. This, of course, should have been `export LESS=-JFMNQRSi`. For reasons that I still do not quite understand, the byobu launcher called byobu proper with a command line argument: `/usr/bin/byobu LESS=-JFMNQRSi` -- this caused byobu to exit immediately.